# Not receiving OTP from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

**Note** : First of all I want to say that I have read every single question under this problem but **None** of it solved my problem.
Most of the time people forgot to enable phone login in firebase console. Which is not the case here.

I have used this many times, but **recently** I am **not receiving any OTP** from Firebase.
It's like google has blocked my number or something.

I am getting this message:

**`I/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@984b556`**

I have some points to share:

1. I only have **2 users** and both of them are **myself**.
2. Google shows that I can use 10K phone verifications per month, and I am barely using 100.
3. I have **used this in past and never had a problem**, but this time it's not working at all.
4. I have checked code many times and the number being sent is in valid format **`+<country-code><10-digit-phone-number>`**

This **won't return any kind of error message**.

- What could be the problem here ?
- Are there any free alternative solutions ?

**UPDATE** :

Different number at the end.

**`I/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@ccc32c4`**

Comment: i too have same problem. did you get solution ?

Comment: @Jaycee no, google has blocked my app using the package name I provided.
So I tried creating a whole new project from a whole new email id, but it just won't work at all.
If you get any solutions, let me know. Good luck!

Comment: did you reslove this issue, I have the same problem only for android, ios is running just fine

Comment: @user2905416 No I have not, after that, I made another fiebase project and set it up with the app. But that too did not work! I think google added the app and mobile phone(!) to blocklist.

Comment: I have just resloved this by upgrade version of firebase auth to com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1 (this is the latest version) and add implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0' to project for fire base to check if you are a robot (by recapcha) and add this to my code: FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getFirebaseAuthSettings()
                .setAppVerificationDisabledForTesting(false);

Comment: And also replace:  PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(phone,60,TimeUnit.SECONDS, TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD, mCallbacks);  with   PhoneAuthOptions options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth) .setPhoneNumber(phone)
                        .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .setActivity(this)                 // Activity (for callback binding)
                        .setCallbacks(mCallbacks)          // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
                        .build();
        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);

Answer (score 1):

Firebase doc note :To prevent abuse, Firebase enforces a limit on the number of SMS messages that can be sent to a single phone number within a period of time. If you exceed this limit, phone number verification requests might be throttled. If you encounter this issue during development, use a different phone number for testing, or try the request again later.[here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth)

As an alternative you can add your phone number to test user list. I use it like this in my project.